# Load Raw Public EC Key using hazmat library

Tags: python, encryption, public-key-encryption, elliptic-curve

I have the following private and public keys generated w/ JS:

```
priv: auLHORUBmv5n48jUDA1TskAmJWFi4TFEmjE1GjgjEB8
pub : BFvn-Qk8HWPwgI5ZgCiWxJV5SYdTXbkVz66sgoEslLxotftRGLEOeIPXVcnQD95eETqW9zM7ejB1MqCc0tvR-0g
```

Code to generate (JavaScript):

```
const pair = generateKeyPairSync('ec', { namedCurve: 'prime256v1' })
const privateKeyDer = pair.privateKey.export({ format: 'der', type: 'pkcs8' })
const privateRaw = privateKeyDer.slice(36, 68)
const publicRaw = privateKeyDer.slice(73)
console.log(`priv: ${webSafe64(privateRaw)}`)
console.log(`pub : ${webSafe64(publicRaw)}`)
```

Now, I have Python project that need to load public key using `cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.load_der_public_key()`

```
load_der_public_key(base64.b64decode(publicRaw))
```

I can't seem to figure out how to do that. Keep getting error:

```
Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format or it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm.
```

Tried to convert that string to bytes, and convert base64 to bytes without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing two formats, one is the *raw* public key, the other is the DER encoded public key in *X.509/SPKI* format.

The posted public key:

```
BFvn-Qk8HWPwgI5ZgCiWxJV5SYdTXbkVz66sgoEslLxotftRGLEOeIPXVcnQD95eETqW9zM7ejB1MqCc0tvR-0g
```

is the Base64url encoded raw public key. Hex encoded it has the format *0x04 + x + y* and is 65 bytes in size for secp256r1 (aka prime256v1):

```
045be7f9093c1d63f0808e59802896c495794987535db915cfaeac82812c94bc68b5fb5118b10e7883d755c9d00fde5e113a96f7333b7a307532a09cd2dbd1fb48
```

In Python, the raw public key can be imported with [`from_encoded_point()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ec.EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point) of the *Cryptography* library, e.g.:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ec
import base64

curve = ec.SECP256R1()
publicKeyRaw = base64.urlsafe_b64decode('BFvn-Qk8HWPwgI5ZgCiWxJV5SYdTXbkVz66sgoEslLxotftRGLEOeIPXVcnQD95eETqW9zM7ejB1MqCc0tvR-0g=');
publicKey = ec.EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point(curve, publicKeyRaw);
```

For an import with [`load_der_public_key()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/serialization/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.load_der_public_key), however, the key would have to be exported in X.509/SPKI format and DER encoded in the NodeJS code. This can be achieved e.g. with

```
var publicKeyDer = pair.publicKey.export({ format: 'der', type: 'spki' })
```

Of course, it is also possible to convert between both formats. But since the *Cryptography* library supports the import of both formats, this is actually not necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the very good answer. Yes, maybe I was a bit confused. The thing is that that's all I'm getting from the server,  public raw key. Everything now works great!