# Shared key generation from EC with pycryptodome

Tags: python, cryptography, google-pay, pycryptodome, python-cryptography

I'm curently working on a project were i need to compute an hkdf symetric key.
To do that i need to generate a shared secret from the private key and an ephemeral public key.

For the rest of my work i did use [pycryptodome](https://pycryptodome-master.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) but i can't find in the doc if it allow generation of shared secret. I saw in the futur plan their intention to add [Elliptic Curves (ECIES, ECDH)](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/future.html) since ecdh is based on shared key it wouldn't be suprising if shared key generation is not implemented yet.

I tried using the cryptography lib too but impossible to load my ephemeral key.

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ec

def __compute_shared_secret(ephemeral_public_key: bytearray) -> bytes:
    client_public_key = serialization.load_der_public_key(ephemeral_public_key)
    server_private_key = serialization.load_der_private_key(b"my_private", password=None)
    shared_secret = server_private_key.exchange(ec.ECDH(), client_public_key)
    return shared_secret
```

```sh
Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format or it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm.
```

ephemeral_public_key is base64 encoded and given by the gpay api.

i would like to know if i can do it with pycryptodome and if not if using the cryptography lib only for this part is a good idea.

Comment: _PyCryptodome_ does currently not implement ECDH, so you need another library. _Cryptography_ is an option. The bug is, as the error message already says, probably caused by a wrong encoding or format. `load_der_public_key()` expects a DER encoded key, i.e. you should Base64 decode the key. If the key is PEM encoded there is also `load_pem_public_key()`, check the documentation (_Key Serialization_). But without a sample key, much more can not be said about this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my imput is a public key in bytearray from an ec prime256v1 private key. 
example b64encode(): b'BGMXZBK2aDlWXfR89wHq9DMIG6WL7kxpsUWKjJlH1CxjpsaN4Sdp55wKMhLlCpM4TbOtkLpIRQT179GKZZB0Knw='
i did try load_der and load_pem  but it doesn't work, Does it need header and footer like a real pem file ?

Comment: This is a raw key in uncompressed format: 0x04|x|y and not in X.509/SPKI format (i.e. neither PEM nor DER).

Comment: S. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67221788/9014097) for importing an uncompressed key with _Cryptography_. You have to use `base64.b64decode()` instead of `base64.urlsafe_b64decode()` though. secp256r1 is an alternative name for prime256v1 or NIST P-256 and fits.

Comment: yes thank you for your help, juste the loading of the private key that i use that i don't like. I would have prefer to load it as PKCS #8  rether that a pem file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of @Topaco i ended up making this function:

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ec import ECDH
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ec import EllipticCurvePublicKey
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.ec import SECP256R1
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_private_key

def __compute_shared_secret(ephemeral_public_key: bytes) -> bytes:
    curve = SECP256R1()
    public_key = EllipticCurvePublicKey.from_encoded_point(curve, ephemeral_public_key)
    server_private_key = load_pem_private_key(b'<private_key>', password=None)
    shared_secret = server_private_key.exchange(ECDH(), public_key)
    return shared_secret
```

It work juste fine